# Unhashing an email address string with Java or Groovy

Tags: java, encryption, hash, groovy, cryptography

I have a report which has email addresses that have been hashed. So for example I see...

```
Email Hash
8b405f28e92ea2c7bd4f05197350c876
```

Is there any way to get the original email address from this? Preferably with Java or Groovy?

Comment: Not really, that's the point of the hash. If you could reverse email addresses, you could also reverse passwords or other confidential information.

Comment: Also, they were probably hashed in the report for a reason...

Comment: If you have a lot of time and computing power. It would also help to know the hash algorithm.

Comment: why do haters need to down vote, why can't they just comment and say it can't be done? That answers my question.

Comment: Just guessing: 1. Similar questions WRT hashing have been answered very throughly here on SO, a simple search would have probably sufficed. 2. SO is about helping with coding, not general information. 3. It is very unlikely that this question will be help to others going forward.

Comment: @zaph Well I *assumed* that he had a cluster of Tesla Voltas to go through that...besides, isn't MD5 a breeze since it's a digest and not a secure hash.

Comment: @Kayaman The security or lack of for MD5 does not apply to brute forcing a hash, it has to do with creating collisions on demand. One would need to try all possible emails, that might be easy if it was in a relatively small known set, otherwise difficult.

Comment: @zaph Ah, it did start out as a crypto hash. Still, with the amount of information known (email addresses aren't that complicated after all) this would be quite feasible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: So, downvoting on a stackexchange site now makes you a hater... Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that hash is MD5 based on it's length.

Reversing an MD5 hash by brute force is essentially impossible.

In this case you will have to hash all possible email addresses and compare to the hashes. If the possible email names is small and known there is a good chance of success, otherwise no.